# How to start a song from a listView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I created a list of the songs on the device.

For each item, in my ListView displays the artist name and song name. I wish that when a song is selected, to start the Play, how would I go?

```
StorageFolder musicLibrary = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> musica = await musicLibrary.GetFilesAsync();

if (musica != null)
{
    List<Testo> song = new List<Testo>();
    {           
        foreach (StorageFile storage in musica)
        {
            MusicProperties musicProp = await storage.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();

            song.Add(new Testo
            {
                NomeArtista = musicProp.Artist,
                NomeCanzone = musicProp.Title,
                Anno = (int)musicProp.Year,

            });                            
        }
    }
}

private async void TestiCanzone_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Testo NuovoTesto = e.ClickedItem as Testo;
}
```

I also created a MediaElement

```
<MediaElement x:Name="AudioPlay" Source="" AutoPlay="True"/>
```

Comment: Do you use MVVM and bindings?

Comment: Use the Binding in XAML

Comment: You mean whenever, a song is selected it should be automatically play that song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind `SelectedValue` of your listview to some property on your viewmodel:

```
 <ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAudio, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

On your viewmodel you need to handle changing property:

```
public string SelectedCustomMusic
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedCustomMusic;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.selectedCustomMusic = value;
                this.MusicSource = this.selectedCustomMusic;
                base.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

And then bind `this.MusicSource` to `Source` of your `MediaElement`.